# How can I reduce the number of "if" statements in my code?

Tags: python, optimization

I am trying to make a minecraft resource calculator in Python, but as it will have a decent number of items I feel like using a bunch of if statements to determine user input isn't the best way I could do it.

```
def hoppercalc():
    print(noofitems * 5, "iron")

def pistoncalc():
    print(noofitems * 3, "planks,",
    noofitems * 4, "cobblestone,",
    noofitems, "redstone and iron")

noofitems = int(input("How many items do you want to make? "))
itemname = input("What item do you want to make? ")

if itemname == "hopper":
  hoppercalc()
if itemname == "piston":
  pistoncalc()
```

Comment: Use a dictionary that maps item names to functions to call.

Comment: @Barmar I wonder how many people realize that functions are objects too, and thus are easy to put in a dictionary?

Comment: Or even use `getattr` or `locals()` to access the functions (if safe to do so with user input).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd think about this a little differently. Instead of making a function for each item recipe, just make a table that represents the ingredient quantities, then you can do lookups in it with a single calculation function:

```
recipes = {
    "hopper": {"iron": 5},
    "piston": {"planks": 3, "cobblestone": 4, "redstone": 1, "iron": 1},
}

def show_recipe(item, quantity=1):
    ingredients = recipes[item]
    for name, amount in ingredients.items():
        print(amount * quantity, name)

show_recipe("piston", 2)
```

This prints:

```
6 planks
8 cobblestone
2 redstone
2 iron
```

Now adding a new recipe just involves adding a line in the table, instead of writing a whole new function. If you want to get more sophisticated you can move to having `Enum` classes to represent your items and ingredients, and then put the recipe method on the item class, and so on.

Also note that I made the item quantity a parameter to the function; this is in general a good idea instead of using a global.

Answer (score 0):

You could map the item name to the calculation function:

```
calculations = {'hopper': hoppercalc,
                'piston': pistoncalc}

calculations[itemname]()
```

Answer (score 0):

How about getting rid of two functions and using one?

```
def calc():
    if itemname == "hopper":
        print(noofitems * 5, "iron")  
    elif itemname == "piston":
        print(noofitems * 3, "planks,", noofitems * 4, "cobblestone,",
            noofitems, "redstone and iron")
    return
```

Comment: This hasn't reduced the amount of `if` statements, as requested.

Answer (score 0):

A dirty but quick fix is to take one function calc that gets an attribute itemname. Inside that function, if itemname is hopper, do thee code of hoppercalc, else do the code of pistoncalc.

I'd still recommend a dictionary though. https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries

Some examples here: https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/dictionary

Answer (score 0):

This will help. but this is not the best way to do. you should use dictionary datatype.

```
    def f1():
    print("func one")

    def f2():
    print("func two")

    def f3():
    print("func three")

    def f4():
    print("func four")

    func_list = [f1, f2, f3, f4]
    word_list = ["one", "two", "three", "four"] 

    val = input("Enter :")
    for x in range(len(word_list)):
        if word_list[x] == val:
             func_list[x]()# call the function in list corresponds to list
        else:
             print("wrong entry")
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest below methods, where you don't have to make your own dictionary or list, and use your programs scope to get all things you defined

You can look into sequence of elements from locals and get itemname, if it exists then it will execute

```py
locals().get(itemname + 'calc') and locals().get(itemname + 'calc')()
```

In this case outermost main function, so you can also use globals

```py
globals().get(itemname + 'calc') and globals().get(itemname + 'calc')()
```

I use `.get` on dictionary because if function does not exist it will return `None`. `None` evaluates to `False` so it will not execute next boolean statement

locals will get all instances existing in the present scope, while global gets all globals. Other than these you also have

You can evaluate expression if you trust the input. Eval comes with its own draw back and if user is not trusted it can even delete files for example

```py
eval(itemname + 'calc()')
```